# Twitter Dataset

Tags: data, sentiment-analysis, social-network-analysis, twitter

I have found the following dataset, apparently it is the largest tweet dataset:
https://www.kaggle.com/kazanova/sentiment140

However, I am looking for a dataset of tweets, with columns containing:

Tweet, likes, retweets and comments.

Does anyone know where to source such a dataset or something similar for social-network analysis?

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know where to source such a dataset or something similar for social-network analysis?

Yes, directly from Twitter using their API: https://developer.twitter.com/